# Android app development software

Tags: android

What is the best software for creating Android applications?
This software have to have possibility to make string connection to remote database.
Also, have to have possibility to create or change allready created templates and screens.
One more think I need from that software is possibility to make push notifications for all or just selected users (users who selected some specific category of news or something like that).

Comment: Eclipse with Android SDK :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
or
IntelliJ http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Android SDK http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

Comment: Btw, which Eclipse version should I download?

Comment: Classic will do the trick. Also read through the Android SDK link above for help getting the necessary plugins/components installed.

Comment: And actually, it looks like you can get eclipse bundled with the other items directly from this page all in one http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Yup, I just saw that also. Handsome thing...